# Battery Icon Cannot Be Found

Tags: 11.10, battery, toshiba-satellite

My ubuntu11.10 on Toshiba Satellite L600 cannot find the battery. It doesn't show battery icon. I don't know how much energy left. I am so sad.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `gnome-power-manager` is installed and running.